CKeditor 5 Mentions React Not Displaying
I'm trying to use the CKEditor5's Mention Plugin In a React App
Here is an example of what I'm doing which is copied straight out of their tutorial on their site
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_mention_mentionconfig-MentionConfig.html
But no matter what I do, every time I type the @ symbol in the editor it's not showing the list or anything. Am I missing something here that would allow it to work?
const editorConfiguration = {
  extraPlugins: ['Mention'],
  mention: {
      feeds: [
          {
              marker: '@',
              feed: [ '@Barney', '@Lily', '@Marry Ann', '@Marshall', '@Robin', '@Ted' ],
              minimumCharacters: 1
          }
      ]
  },
};


Can you add a sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/reactjs-playground-h19jh?

So I Was able to look at an old issue and someone mentioned that they had to type
@@ in order to pull up the mentions for some reason. That's when I discovered that the z-index was off and hiding behind my modal the entire time and why I couldn't see it.
I'm not sure why I have to @@ in order to see the Dropdown though it's kind of weird since the example on the site only needs one. I Think the zindex issue is a bug since I'm triggering it inside a modal
